# How do you use functions from a different header file in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to divide "functions" and "GUI" to different header files to make the code more convenient to read. However, I can't use the functions that I've implemented in my second header file after importing it to my first one.
This is a function:

```
def openNewWindow():
newWindow = Toplevel()
newWindow.title("Help")
newWindow.geometry("200x200")
Label(newWindow,
        text ="This is a guider").pack(main)
```

And this is the GUI:

```
    Help = Button(settingFrame, image=test, text="help", width=388, height=50,
        compound="c", fg="red", command = lambda :[openNewWindow]))
        Help.place(x=10, y=55)
```

When I try to click on the "Help" button it says that "NameError: name 'openNewWindow' is not defined". How to solve that problem?

Comment: How do you import file?

Comment: In GUI file: from function import *. In function file: from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox import webbrowser

Comment: In your GUI file try at the beginning if you can run the function there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that problem, I needed to run the function file first and then the GUI file. That way, the function file "updates" and then the GUI file accepts the updated data.